# Carl Jung Psychology Analysis Book

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, jung

I am Computer Engineer, but i feel strong partiality towards Jungian Psychology. I would like to find the Analysis research book on Carl Jung about

- The Process of Individuation
- Shadow

I seem to know the books written by Jung himself, However, I need some advanced, and in-depth book regarding interpreting above subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Shadow

Jeffrey, S. (n.d.). *A Definitive Guide to Jungian Shadow Work: How to Get to Know and Integrate Your Dark Side* https://scottjeffrey.com/shadow-work/
provides some information on Shadow Work.

> This guide explores the nature of the shadow and provides tips and exercises for daily shadow work.

And

Fordham, M. (1965). The importance of analysing childhood for assimilation of the shadow. *Journal of Analytical Psychology, 10*(1), 33-47. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1465-5922.1965.00033.x
is a research paper on the subject.

> Examination of the empirical data and the ideas about the shadow which Jung presents to us in his published work and his seminars shows that no single definition is adequate to elucidate what he means to represent by the term. Therefore we shall start by demonstrating the usefulness of having this concept in mind as a metaphor that helps to organize a number of data from different fields. Later on, we shall employ definitions as instruments to further discussion.

The Encyclopedia of Psychology and Religion at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-6086-2_635 lists many books and articles on the subject.

### Individuation

Martin Schmidt wrote a paper called *Individuation and the self* and a free PDF of the paper is available from the Society of Analytical Psychology at https://www.thesap.org.uk/resources/articles-on-jungian-psychology-2/about-analysis-and-therapy/individuation/

> Jung’s thinking about the Self and its dynamic of individuation separates Jungian analytical psychology from other psychoanalytical schools.   He uses the concept of the Self to describe his understanding of who we are and the concept of individuation to describe the process by which we can fulfil our potential to become all that we can be.

The Encyclopedia of Psychology and Religion at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-6086-2_329 lists many books and articles on the subject.